# Using "apply" to increase speed in R

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, apply

EDITED: I edited the code below in response to some of your suggestions (i got rid of the prop.test function and climbed out of the second circle of hell).  Im curious what the next steps would be in terms of making this faster.  Should I start using apply or parallel processing, or something else?

My main goal is to make this run faster.  As I said, I'm pretty new to this, so I'd appreciate any advice.  Thanks for the help!

```
number.of.trials<-500
n.limit<-1000
final.n.list<-numeric(number.of.trials)

for (trials in 1:number.of.trials){
  p.value<-2
  n<-1
  a<-0
  b<-0

  #this while loop stops once test shows significance or when n reaches the limit
  while ((p.value > .05 | p.value==0) & n<=n.limit) {

    ##add new data points to a and b
    a<-a+rbinom(1, 1, .5)
    b<-b+rbinom(1, 1, .5)

    ##calculate chi-square test statistic with continuity correction
    yates.stat<-2*n*(abs(a*(n-b)-b*(n-a))-n)^2/(n*n*(a+b)*(2*n-a-b)) 

    ##calculate p-value
    p.value<-pchisq(q=yates.stat, df=1, lower.tail=FALSE)
    n<-n+1
  }
  final.n.list[trials]<-n-1
}
```

Explanation of what I'm trying to do with this code:
This is a simulation of an experiment where the two groups (a and b) are tested to see if they are significantly different from each other continually throughout the entire experiment.  I would like to demonstrate how the traditional p-value does not work in this context.  The experiment ends when both groups have a sample size of 1000 (or if the groups appear to be significantly different at any time during the experiment), and I repeat the entire experiment 500 times.

Comment: What OS are you running? Windows, OSX, or Linux?  If you have multiple cores at your disposable, you can use the ``apply`` family in the ``parallel`` package.

Comment: Parallelization would be _extremely_ premature. First you must climb your way out of the [Second Circle of Hell](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).

Comment: ...you're next step would probably be to write your own, extremely stripped down, version of `prop.test`. There's a lot of cruft in there that you probably don't need.

Comment: Joran is exactly right

Comment: Thanks @joran for your advice.  Getting rid of the growing vector increased speed a little, and writing the equation (rather than using the prop.test function) made a huge difference. I added the updated version in the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already been given several bits of advice that point to the effectiveness of your coding for the CONTENT of your loop. Should you be calling `rbinom()` to generate single values multiple times? Why not generate a large number, say 1000 at a time, 500 each, and then work through them, possibly with `mapply`? The people you read who are claiming efficiencies with `apply()` are really quite wrong. Loops are loops regardless of generation as `while()` or `for()` or `apply()` loops. The key is learning to use vectorized strategies.

Comment: I agree.  Even looking at the source for `apply` is daunting.  I don't see a shred of C code/calls in there, all R code...and yet I still use it.

Comment: The C code would be in calls to `vapply` where it sends to `.Internal(vapply, ....)`